# Restore upgrade after crash ssh

Tags: debian, ssh, upgrade, whiptail

My ssh connection crashed during a whiptail about php.ini. (update apache)

Is there a way to recover everything smoothly ?

```
root     20689  0.0  0.0  20036  2284 pts/1    S+   10:15   0:00 whiptail --backtitle Package configuration --title Modif
```

`apt-get upgrade` give me :

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the lock file:

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

And try again:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Please add to the answer, explaining and giving alternatives of what to do next.